# What is the best tool for scrum in TFS

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum

I'm currently giving a try to the new Visual Studio Scrum template and I'm looking for a the best approach and tools to enhanced product backlog management and tracking work progression. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Urban Turtle (http://urbanturtle.com) is the first tool to specifically support the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum process template (http://urbanturtle.com/blog/2010/07/08/urban-turtle-3-2-now-available/).

Comment: In January 2010, Microsoft review Urban Turtle and Brian Harry says '...awesome Scrum experience for TFS'. Read the full blog from Brian Harry here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/01/05/urban-turtle-for-scrum-and-tfs.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Let me tout my own horn for a bit, and recommend an Open Source tool I developed for my own use: [Scrum Sprint Monitor (link to CodePlex)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223144651/http://scrumsprintmonitor.codeplex.com/). The process template you are using does not give Scrum Sprint Monitor some of the info it needs to be extra useful, but it would be very easy to add the 1 or 2 fields missing (work done and 1 other) to the process template and change the process template adapter class in the project to take advantage of them. Let me know if you are interested and I can help you through the process.

Answer (score 1):

We use Rally ( http://www.rallydev.com) at our company and we're happy with it.

Prior to that we used VersionOne ( http://www.versionone.com) and it was decent.

Our company spent a good amount of time investigating and I find Rally does the job real well. Rally is hosted, which has actually turned out to be a good thing. VersionOne isn't that i'm aware of; we hosted it locally. Both provide free trials and they're willing to engage in migration efforts.

Comment: Rally has a very steep learning curve, and its interface is very non-intuitive. It also makes it very difficult for developers to update their progress. This is based on my experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tfs you should seriously consider this:[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaronbjork/announcing-team-foundation-server-scrum-v1-0-beta)

This has been made in collaboration with Ken Schwaber the inventor of the Scrum. I've used actively rallydev & versionone in the past but they are too heavy, and therefore... Less agile.

Answer (score 0):

The MFS template included with TFS has been adequate for our needs.  We have a small group of 8 developers working on multiple projects.